# MVC db context overuse?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added a database repository layer to my MVC application which does the CRUD. Sometimes my controllers need to call multiple db repositories and I do this by calling the db respitories I need. This in turn creates multiple db context objects. One for each repository. Should there be multiple db context objects or should I pass in a single db context to the repository object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you should use one dbContext. Because When you try to update your model in db, you may get error. Because of different dbContext.

Check [HERE](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works a treat! Now I have to go through all my code and change it.

Answer (score 1):

There should be only one, I highly recommend using Unit of Work pattern:

Here's a quick and simple example:

```
public interface IUoW : IDisposable
{
    MyDbContext DbContext { get; set; }  

    void SaveChanges();
}

public class UoW : IUoW
{
    public MyDbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    public UoW()
    {
        DbContext = new MyDbContext();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You need to instantiate UoW once for each request and pass it to your repository:

```
public class MyRepository
{
    private MyDbContext _context;

    public MyRepository(IUoW uow)
    {
        _context = uow.MyDbContext;
    }

    // your crud methods
}
```

Of course it's just a very simple example of it and I've seen people implement this pattern in many different ways.